# UISplitViewController master view calling performSegueWithIdentifier on detail view

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uisplitviewcontroller, unwind-segue

I am calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` on a detail view controller from my master `UIViewController`.

For some reason, the segue is not performing. It is an unwind segue. I have the `IBAction` in place in the view controller I am segueing too. I have the unwind segue setup to point to that action. The master view controller has the correct reference to the detail view controller. I change a color on the detail just to make sure I am referencing the right thing. Also, if I type the name of the identifier wrong it crashes. If I type it correctly, it runs just fine as if it knows it is there.

But it just won't segue!

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the `UISplitViewController` needs `UINavigationControllers` as its master and detail view for an unwind segue to work. Even though you can perform a push segue without a `UINavigationController` it seems a `UINavigationController` is necessary for an unwind segue.